# req.body.something returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have been trying to post data to my express server using axios, and when I console.log(req.body.something) it returns undefined, and when I console.log(req.body) only it logs this message to the console:
[Object: null prototype] { '{"nameVal":"Usef","nickNameVal":"US"}': '' }
Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

```
// This My Server.js Code
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
const urlencodedparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

// Use Cors As MiddleWhere
app.use(cors());

// Get The Post Request
app.post("/user", urlencodedparser, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.name); // returns undefined
});

app.listen(5000);

// and this the react component state along with the axios post request

  state = {
    nameVal: "Usef",
    nickNameVal: "US"
  };

 handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { nameVal, nickNameVal } = this.state;
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user", { nameVal, nickNameVal },
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }
  ).then(res => {console.log(res)});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove your custom `Content-Type` header from the axios request, axios will send your data as JSON by default, and it will be parsed by your express JSON parser middleware.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user", { nameVal, nickNameVal })
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

The data you send to the server is `nameVal` and `nickNameVal`, so trying to access `req.body.name` will still give `undefined`. Try logging `nameVal` and `nickNameVal` instead.

```
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.nameVal, req.body.nickNameVal);
});
```

Comment: yeah that makes sense, Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) you need to pass an instance of `URLSearchParams` (or a query string of the parameters) as the second argument.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('nameVal', state.nameVal);
params.append('nickNameVal', state.nickNameVal);
axios.post('/user', params);
```